# easylogging++ how avoid multiple init

Tags: c++, logging, visual-studio-2015, easylogging++

my dll has 2 entry points and I wish use `EasyLogging++` with both entries..

I tried to use this header:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef EASYLOGGING_LOADER_H
#define EASYLOGGING_LOADER_H

#include "easylogging++.h"

INITIALIZE_EASYLOGGINGPP

#endif
```

but with this file included, I get the errors like this:

```
Error   LNK2005 "class std::shared_ptr<class el::base::Storage> el::base::elStorage" (?elStorage@base@el@@3V?$shared_ptr@VStorage@base@el@@@std@@A) already defined in gInput.obj
```

any ideas on solve this? thanks

ps. i'm using the `Easylogging++ v9.96.4`

Comment: He was following my advice (45 mins ago)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the macro `INITIALIZE_EASYLOGGINGPP` defines a variable. If you include the header file in multiple [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) then you break [the one definition rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule) and will get an error.

The simple solution is to invoke the macro only *once* in your whole project, by doing it in a single source file.

Comment: thanks @some! but how can I do this? is not possible check the macro definition?

Comment: @ghiboz You do it exactly as you do now, but in a source file instead. Then remove the header file you show in your question, it's not needed.